# Resize, crop, and trim videos

Tags: conversion

How do I crop and resize about 6000 mp4-movies? They are all 1280 x 800. I need to crop the bottom 100 px and remove the first 4 seconds of each movie. Can this be done with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-encode all vids to crop the bottom 100 px - you have to decide which codecs you want to use.... and think about the filters - this depends on the sourcefile.... The ffmpeg code is:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUTFILE -ss 00:00:04 -map v -vf "crop=out_h=in_h-100:y=0" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy OUTPUTFILE
```

The best would be to iterate the INPUTFILEs by a for-loop. put the new files in a new directory and you won't have any problems with the names.

Comment: First of all, a big thank you for helping me! Now, as I said I'm totally new at this. To use this code, I have to put it in the Ffmpeg console? If I put it in parameter, I get an error. I suppose INPUTFILE refers to the name of the file. I see you mention iterate the inputiles by a fo-loop. How do I do this. Also, thank you for your patience with me :D